# What to do when neural network(NEAT) neuron becomes too negative?

Tags: neural-network, neat

I'm working on a **NEAT** neural network and 
i'm not sure how to handle neurons that reach a **negative action potential**.

If a neuron's action potential reaches a certain threshold it fires and it's action potential is set back to 0, so it doesn't fire over and over again.

But what do you do if a neuron receives mostly inhibitory signals?
Do you let his action potential fall to negative infinity or do cap it's max-negative value?

Do you just reset it back to 0 if it reaches a negative threshold?

Comment: Define 'action potential'